# Retrieving data from mysql in Java

Tags: mysql

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");  
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "parin");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();


        String query="Select * from Liblogin;";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        String username=rs.getString("username");
        String password=rs.getString("password");


        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();


        String enteredUsername=t1.getText().toString();
        String enteredPassword = new String(t2.getText());
        if(enteredUsername.contentEquals(username)&&enteredPassword.contentEquals(password))
        {
            Homepage a=new Homepage();
            a.setVisible(true); 
            this.dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Incorrect name and password.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve my password and username from mysql database.But unable to do so because of some exception(Sql exception:Before start of result set.).

Comment: Have you ever read the documentation for `ResultSet` class, by any chance? This question is trivial.

Comment: Sorry yes.I got the mistake.
while(rs.next())
            {
                username=rs.getString("username");
                password=rs.getString("password");
            }while(rs.next())
            {
                username=rs.getString("username");
                password=rs.getString("password");
            }

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `rs.first();` or `rs.next();` before trying to read the values from a ResultSet row.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first%28%29

Calling `rs.next();` is especially handy in a while-loop to process all the rows in the ResultSet.

```
// Get a result set from SQL query
while (rs.next()) {
   // Process this row
}
```